# shiny: renderUI() does not show up

Tags: r, shiny

i'm currently trying to build a shiny app. The user provides a data frame (i've chosen mtcars from the car-package).
Then the user should be able to pick a dependent variable in the shiny app. Dependent on the picked variable, all other variables of the data frame should pop up, and the user then will pick the independent variables.
My files are organized in an ui.R and server.R file as follows:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        selectInput("dep", label = "Select dep variable",
                 choices = colnames(mtcars)),
        uiOutput("indepVars")
    )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$indepVars <- renderUI({
        depVar<-which(colnames(mtcars)==as.character(input$dep))
        checkboxGroupInput("variables1", label="Include variables:", 
                         choices = colnames(mtcars)[-depVar], 
                         selected = colnames(mtcars)[-depVar])
    })
}
```

My problem is, that the uiOutput() doesn't show, and i really don't know why. I guess, my understanding of renderUI() is somehow wrong, is there some initial value i have to set?

Comment: It works fine for me with shiny 1.0.3. There are some inbalanced brackets in your code. You are using `renderUI` and `uiOutput` correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying! I updated R and the shiny package, and it is not working, but i will run the code monday at work. Thanks again!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: I changed my R version today to R.3.3.3, and now everything is fine.